# Left Join Equivalent on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have my function to get a list of departments  where i do a left join from 2 tables, i want to know how can i make the equivalent on codeigniter way? my code is this:

```
 function get_department_list()
 {
      $sql = '
      SELECT
      a.employee_name,
      b.department_name
      FROM
      tbl_employee a 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_department b ON b.department_id = a.department_id';

      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
 }
```

I was reading the codeigniter documentation and tried to do it the CI way but i only get errors, this is how i tried to do it:

```
 function get_department_list()
 {
      $sql = '
      $this->db->select('a.employee_name','b.department_name');
      $this->db->from('tbl_employee a');
      $this->db->join('tbl_employee b', 'b.department_id = a.department_id', 'left');
      $query = $this->db->get();

      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
 }
```

This is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CI-Employee/application/models/Department_model.php
>   on line 13 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Parsing Error
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING)
>
> Filename: models/Department_model.php
>
> Line Number: 13

Backtrace:

Any help will be really appreciated thanks guys!

EDIT:

This was my solution and thanks guys for your time!

```
 function get_department_list()
 {
      $this->db->select('a.employee_name,b.department_name');
      $this->db->from('tbl_employee a');
      $this->db->join('tbl_department b', 'b.department_id = a.department_id', 'left'); 
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$department_name

Filename: views/department_view.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CI-Employee/application/views/department_view.php
Line: 24
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CI-Employee/application/controllers/Department.php
Line: 19
Function: view

Comment: line 19 is this one:    <td><?php echo $deptlist[$i]->department_name; ?></td>

Comment: and this is not a duplicate its not near similar of what i am asking for help